# How to store different outputs inside a funcion?

Tags: r, function

---

I want to store different output variables that are calculated inside a function.
I coded a toy example:

```
f = function(number) 
{

  xx = NULL
  savexx = NULL
  savexx10 = NULL
  for (i in 1:10) {
  x = number*i
  xx = c(xx,x)
  }

  save_phrase = "hello"
  savexx = xx        
  savexx10 = xx*10
  save = cbind(savexx,savexx10)

}

store = f(1)
store
```

But with this code it is returning only the variable `save = cbind(savexx,savexx10)`.
I would like to save all the 4 variables that are created inside this function.

Is it possible doing this without using a dataframe or a list?

Comment: It is impossible. You can try to save it to a global environment but I don't think it is a good solution. What is wrong with using a `list`?

Comment: Marta your answer was very good. Nothing wrong with the list, it was just to know if there is a possibility to do this, it seems it's not. Post your answer if you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible without a `list`. `List` would be better than a `data.frame` because it can store different types of variables (`vector`, `table`, `plot` ect.) Try to do it like here:

```
f = function(number) 
{

xx = NULL
savexx = NULL
savexx10 = NULL
for (i in 1:10) {
  x = number*i
  xx = c(xx,x)
}

lista <- list()

lista$save_phrase = "hello"
lista$savexx = xx        
lista$savexx10 = xx*10
lista$save = cbind(lista$savexx, lista$savexx10)

lista

}

store = f(1)

# whole list:
store

# elements of a list:
store$save_phrase
store$savexx
store$savexx10
store$save
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) list** We can return the desired variables in a list.

```
f2 = function(number) {

    xx = NULL
    savexx = NULL
    savexx10 = NULL
    for (i in 1:10) {
      x = number*i
      xx = c(xx,x)
    }

    list(save_phrase = "hello", 
      savexx = xx,        
      savexx10 = xx*10,
      save = cbind(savexx,savexx10))

}

store = f2(1)
```

**2) mget** Another way to do this is to use `mget` if the returned variables have a pattern to their names as in this case:

```
f3 = function(number) {

    xx = NULL
    savexx = NULL
    savexx10 = NULL
    for (i in 1:10) {
      x = number*i
      xx = c(xx,x)
    }

    save_phrase = "hello"
    savexx = xx        
    savexx10 = xx*10
    save = cbind(savexx,savexx10)

    mget(ls(pattern = "save"))

}

store = f3(1)
```

**3) gsubfn** gsubfn has a facility for placing the list components into separate variables.  After this is run `save_phrase`, `savexx`, `savexx10` and `save` will exists as separate variables.

```
library(gsubfn)
list[save_phrase, savexx, savexx10, save] <- f2(1)
```

**4) attach** Although this is not really recommended you can do this:

```
attach(f2(1), name = "f2")
```

This will create an entry on the search list with the variables that were returned so we can just refer to `save_phrase`, `savexx`, `savexx10` and `save`.  We can see the entry using `search()` and `ls("f2")` and we can remove the entry using  `detach("f2")` .

**5) assign**  Another possibility which is not really recommended but does work is to assign the components right into a specific environment.  Now `save_phrase`, `savexx`, `savexx10` and `save` will all exist in the global environment.

```
list2env(f2(1), .GlobalEnv)
```

Similarly this will inject those variables into the current environment.  This is the same as the prior line if the current environment is the global environment.

```
list2env(f2(1), environment())
```

**6)** Again, I am not so sure this is a good idea but we could modify `f` to inject the outputs right into the parent frame.  After this is run `save_phrase`, `savexx`, `savexx10` and `save` will all exist in the current environment.

```
f4 = function(number, env = parent.frame()) {

    xx = NULL
    savexx = NULL
    savexx10 = NULL
    for (i in 1:10) {
      x = number*i
      xx = c(xx,x)
    }

    env$save_phrase = "hello"
    env$savexx = xx
    env$savexx10 = xx*10
    env$save = cbind(savexx,savexx10)

    invisible(env)

}

f4(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

R functions only return a SINGLE object. If you want multiple objects returned they *have* to be combined into a list or some other type of object.

Some languages like python let us do stuff like this:

```
a, b = mult_return_func()
```

But R will only return a single object. R programmers typically use lists to return multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no return statement, then R will return the value of the last evaluated expression in the function.

This would explain why it is returning `save = cbind(savexx,savexx10)`.

To return multiple values you will need a list or another object because the R return function can only return a single object.

My suggestion would be to add those values to a list, return the list, and then get the variables from the list.

I hope that helps. If you'd like to read more then I suggest going to https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/return-function/